# Error with multiple components/classes for TabBar in react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, tabbar

In my react-native app, I have implemented a TabBar and now am aiming to have various components (each defined in their own classes) load upon selection of each tab. However, I'm currently getting this error: "onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child", when I try to select a tab on the TabBar.

```
var Create = require('./Create');
var Feed = require('./Feed');

var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons');

var HomePage = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <TabBarIOS
                tintColor="white"
                barTintColor="darkslateblue">
            <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
                title="FEED"
                iconName="ios-star"
                selectedIconName="ios-star"
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'feed'}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'feed',
                    });
                }}>
            </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
            <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
                title="CREATE"
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'create'}
                iconName="ios-person"
                selectedIconName="ios-person"
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedTab: 'greenTab',
                    });
                }}>
            </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
        </TabBarIOS>
        );
    },
});
```

EDIT: Including Feed.js:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});

class Feed extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                    Feed page!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Feed;
```

I can't determine what is causing this error and also am not sure if this is the right way to go about loading various components from different files. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error probably because you are not providing any view to `TabBarItemIOS`. **You have to provide ONE `View` to `TabBarItemIOS`**

This is how I'd implement TabBarIOS.

An object containing names of all views-

```
var TABS = {
    upcoming: 'upcoming',
    search: 'search',
    popular: 'popular',
    watchlist: 'watchlist',
    logout: 'logout'
}
```

And inside render method, something like this -

```
render: function(){
        _this=this;
        return(
                <TabBarIOS translucent={true}>
                    <Icon.TabBarItem
                        title="Upcoming"
                        iconName="arrow-graph-up-right"
                        selectedIconName="arrow-graph-up-right"
                        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedTab: TABS.upcoming})}
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.upcoming}
                    >
                        {this._renderHome()}
                    </Icon.TabBarItem>
                    <Icon.TabBarItem
                        title="Search"
                        iconName="ios-search"
                        selectedIconName="ios-search-strong"
                        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedTab: TABS.search})}
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.search}
                    >
                        {this._renderSearch()}
                    </Icon.TabBarItem>                  
                    <Icon.TabBarItem
                        title="Popular"
                        iconName="android-star-outline"
                        selectedIconName="android-star"
                        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedTab: TABS.popular})}
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.popular}
                    >
                        {this._renderPopular()}
                    </Icon.TabBarItem>
                    <Icon.TabBarItem
                        title="Watchlist"
                        iconName="ios-list-outline"
                        selectedIconName="ios-list"
                        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedTab: TABS.watchlist})}
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.watchlist}
                    >
                        {this._renderBlank('Your Watchlist')}
                    </Icon.TabBarItem>
                    <Icon.TabBarItem
                        title="Logout"
                        iconName="log-out"
                        selectedIconName="log-out"
                        onPress={this._logout}
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === TABS.logout}
                    >
                    </Icon.TabBarItem>                  
                </TabBarIOS>
        )
    },
```

And then render individual views through functions like this one-

```
_renderHome: function(){
    return(
        <HomeView navigator={this.props.navigator} />
    )
},
```

Back when I was new to React Native, I had created a sample app. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/mihir-harbinger/explore-movies/blob/master/src/components/inapp/homeIOS.js) file to clear any doubts.

Comment: hi @Mihir, I modified my file to use _render functions, and am still getting the same error. Could it be due to something wrong in the view itself (ie, the Feed.js file?)

Comment: @user3802348 Can you update your answer with your feed.js file?

Comment: @user3802348 look fine to me! I don't know what's going wrong. Create a sample app on [rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/) so that I can see entire code.

Comment: I just figured out the issue. I had a line commented out in the render function on the HomePage. When I removed this line, the code worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3802348 strange! :D Anyways, glad that your code worked.